# Filter Woocommerce products based on custom product attribute value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

In Woocommerce, I have a product attribute called `restriction_id`. I am wanting to filter the products based on certain **restriction id's**. For example if a value is set to **`35`** in a php session variable I want to filter out any product that has the attribute for restriction_id set to **`35`**.

What would I put in here?

Here is my starting code:

```
// Define the woocommerce_product_query callback 
function action_woocommerce_product_query( $q, $instance ) { 
    // The code
}; 
// Add the action
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', __NAMESPACE__.'\\action_woocommerce_product_query', 10, 2 );
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can find a working solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74200775/how-can-i-filter-woocommerce-shop-products-product-loop-by-their-custom-produc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated: Try the following [tax query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) instead:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_query_tax_query', 'custom_product_query_meta_query', 10, 2 );
function custom_product_query_meta_query( $tax_query, $query ) {
    if( is_admin() ) return $tax_query;

    // HERE set the taxonomy of your product attribute (custom taxonomy)
    $taxonomy = 'pa_restriction_id'; // Note: always start with "pa_" in Woocommerce

    // HERE Define your product attribute Terms to be excluded
    $terms = array( '35' ); // Note: can be a 'term_id', 'slug' or 'name'

    // The tax query
    $tax_query[] = array(
        'taxonomy'         => $taxonomy,
        'field'            => 'slug', // can be a 'term_id', 'slug' or 'name'
        'terms'            => $terms,
        'operator'         => 'NOT IN', // Excluded
    );

    return $tax_query;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I can't get this code to work. It omits everything. I've also tried changing the operator to 'IN'  which also omits everything...

Comment: The "restriction_id" is the name of the custom product attribute. All my products are simple products. Not all products may have a custom restriction_id. At the moment I have set two products with a restriction_id of 35. I have done this in the woocommerce backend under the attributes section of product data

Comment: I say custom, because when I go to add an attribute to add a new one it says "custom product attribute" and then an add button. While you try on the test server I'll have a look to see if I can use "Tags" to make it do what I need

Comment: @RichardThompson I've developed a solution for custom product attributes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74200775/how-can-i-filter-woocommerce-shop-products-product-loop-by-their-custom-produc