# Woocommerce - Disable or Hide product based on custom field value (ACF)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to hide products on my site based on logical conditions with their custom field values *(provided by Advanced Custom Fields Plugin - **ACF**).*

I have referenced a number of articles about excluding products based on certain criteria, testing with the `pre_get_posts`, `woocommerce_product_query_tax_query` and `woocommerce_product_query` hooks. All of which won't let me access the ACF values so that I can filter the `$tax_query` terms.

My end goal here is to hide specific products that have a date set in its custom field and that date is in the past. I access the custom field using the `get_field('event_date');` function.

I am looking for someone to help me develop this code to filter products based on their Advanced Custom Field value.

There is a lot I have tried so far, and I've looked at the `var_dumps` to see what I can use, but the truth is I'm still at square one. Here is my laughable progress:

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_query', 'filter_past_events');
function filter_past_events($q)
{
    // Return is event_date variable is not set
    if (get_field('event_date')) {
        $eventDate = new DateTime(get_field('event_date')); // Format ISO-8601 (YYYY-MM-DD)
        $now = new DateTime();
        if ($eventDate < $now) {
            // event is in the past
        }
    }
}
```

So far, I have referenced:

• [Exclude products from a particular category on the shop page](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/exclude-a-category-from-the-shop-page/)

• [filter-woocommerce-products-based-on-custom-product-attribute-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49555463/filter-woocommerce-products-based-on-custom-product-attribute-value)

Comment: Instead of using ACF, you should better use normal hand coded custom fields,  where you will be able to access the data through a meta query.

Comment: Hi @LoicTheAztec, I agree with what you're saying, however, I am using ACF for its sheer convenience and versatility. I did find this though that may be able to help me... https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/

Answer (score 0):

```
function custom_pre_get_posts_query($q) {
    $meta_query   = $q->get('meta_query');
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key'     => 'key',
        'value'   => 'value',
        'compare' => '!='
    );

    $q->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
}

add_action('woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_pre_get_posts_query');
```

Comment: To enhance the quality of your answer, please add comments to your code , or a line or 2 to explain why this works to answer OP's question